# Is the UK experiencing wage growth for people on low incomes?

Tags: politics, economics, united-kingdom

In a TV interview with Andrew Marr on 3 Oct 2021, UK Prime Minister Boris Johnson claimed that UK wages were growing for people on low incomes. The interviewer (Marr) said that wasn't true - Johnson insisted that it was.

Who was right?

> [Johnson] told Marr: “What you're also seeing is finally growth in
> wages, after more than 10 years of flat-lining what you’re seeing is
> people on low incomes being paid more and by the way, here an example
> -”
>
> However, Marr interrupted Johnson to challenge him on this point.
>
> “– Can I come directly to that, because you’ve said something that
> isn’t true I’m afraid, you’ve said something that isn’t true about
> wages -”
>
> Though Johnson quickly responded and remained insistent that they
> were.
>
> “- Wages are growing,” he replied.
>
> But Marr didn’t stop there and referred to data from the Office of
> National Statistic.
>
> He said: “The Office of National Statistics, the ONS, your our own
> body, in the last reporting period – the three months running to July
> – says that wages are not keeping pace with inflation.
>
> “So in other words, in real terms, over the last three months, wages
> have gone down, not up.”
>
> As Marr continued talking, Johnson appeared to be shaking his head in
> disagreement, to which Marr responded: “You’re shaking your head but
> these are ONS government figures.”
>
> But Johnson refused to relent and replied: “No, wages are finally
> going up for the low paid and they’re going up faster by the way than
> they are for those on high incomes and about time too.”
>
> “Well, that’s not what the numbers are showing,” Marr remarked.
>
> “That is what the numbers are showing,” Johnson hit back. “And it’s
> about time we had that in this country – wages have been totally
> flatlining for more than a decade and what we would rather do is help
> people into better paid, better-skilled jobs which is what is
> happening.”

[Moment Andrew Marr calls out Boris Johnson for ‘not telling the truth’ over wages increasing](https://www.indy100.com/politics/andrew-marr-boris-johnson-wages-b1931415), Sinead Butler, The Independent, 3 Oct 2021

Original video: [Boris Johnson on UK wages](https://twitter.com/BBCPolitics/status/1444593048911073280), BBC Politics (Twitter), 3 Oct 2021

Comment: Comments are to improve the question, not for pretend answers.

Comment: You can look at year-on-year changes, or you can look at year-compared-to-before-covid changes. Covid caused a massive drop. Now we have a massive increase. Which barely gets us back to before Covid.